# Problems with OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

read the following code.

```
View.OnClickListener obj_object = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button Temp_Button = (Button) v;
        String tempButtonText= Temp_Button.getText().toString();
        String tempEdtText =  ED.getText().toString();
        ED.setText(tempEdtText + tempButtonText);
    };
};
```

I am new in android so I created a button and I google to make an event and it successfully fired. Now I have some questions about it

1. I want to cast View v to button like this Button `Temp_Button = (Button) v;` but it's not allowing me to cast in this way.
2. why there's an function onClick(View v) because In functions in java we just write function then define body but in this case there's another function inside a function.
3. why semi colons are there at closing brackets because semi colons not come after the closing brackets of then why here.

I am really confused between java and the java with android.

Comment: How do you attach this OnClickListener?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `Button Temp_Button = (Button)v;` what do you mean by _"not allowing me"_?

Comment: I just paste the event

Comment: Do you mean it crashes (stops working)?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I want to cast View v to button like this Button Temp_Button =
>   (Button)v; but it's not allowing me to cast in this way.

There is nothing wrong with `Button Temp_Button = (Button)v;`.

> 2) why there's an function onClick(View v) because In functions in
>   java we just write function then define body but in this case there's
>   another function inside a function.

`View.OnClickListener` is an interface. What you are doing in the above code is creating an *anonymous class definition* based on the `View.OnClickListener` interface.

*An anonymous class in Java is a class not given a name and is both declared and instantiated in a single statement.*

Read more about them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) and [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-an-anonymous-class-in-java.html)

> 3) why semi colons are there at closing brackets because semi colons
>   not come after the closing brackets of then why here.

As for semi-colons, the one after the end brace of `onClick()` is not required, since end of **methods** do not need semi-colons. But the last one is required as end of **variable declarations** (such as `int a=0;`)  need the ending semi-colon. Since you are declaring a variable `obj_object` you need one.

```
View.OnClickListener obj_object = new View.OnClickListener() { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll address some of the questions:

1. `OnClickListener` is not a function, it's an interface. You're declaring a new class implementing this interface in the line `View.OnClickListener obj_object = new View.OnClickListener()`. `public void onClick(View v)` is then a function in this class.

See more on [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

1. As for semicolons, they are required at the end of statements in Java.

Comment: thanks a lot for solving this issue can you differentiate a class from an interface

Comment: What do you mean? Once is declares with `class`, the other `interface`.

Comment: mean functionality wise.

Comment: Try do do some reading on that. That's too broad for Stack Exchange format of questions and asnwers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a `Button` object from a `View` Parameter on initialization of a `View.OnClickListener`. 
You would need to create a **new** Button object, and/or findViewById:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// whatever code you have here....

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        String tempButtonText= v.getText().toString();
        String tempEdtText =  ED.getText().toString();

        ED.setText(tempEdtText + tempButtonText);

        };

    });

}
```

hope this help, Happy Coding!

Comment: then why semi colons are there normally semi colons are not with functions

Comment: You could put this in onCreate() of your `Activity`, see edit